# Hover and onclick functionality issue in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I want to have onclick and hover functionality simultaneously but if you have clicked somewhere then hover should not work until I click somewhere else. I have tried alot but I didn't find any working code. Kindly help

```
 canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(evt) {
    }, false);
canvas.onmousemove = function(evt) {   

 };
```

Comment: Please provide us with _something_ that you have tried

Comment: I have added the code. Kindly check

Comment: That's not jquery or node.

Comment: you can make two calls on click, the hover is just an event. So on click you can make the click call and the hover call ( assuming hover call is just css or function call that needs to happen ). That's how i understood it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am not quite sure what you need and why you need it. But, in that short piece of code you wrote I saw the word "*canvas*" and thought "*what the heck, that could be fun!*". I have not much experience with the canvas element since earlier, so I realize there may be better ways of writing this code.

But, I hope what I wrote in the below example is at least close to what you were looking for. Otherwise, go nuts and change and adapt the way you like... and while you do that, try to learn something of it.

```js
var Canvas = function() {
  this.$canvas = $('canvas');
  this.$currPos = $('#currPos');
  this.$currClick = $('#currClick');
  this.$clickInfo = $('#clickInfo');
  
  this.canvsWidth = 150;
  this.cavasHeight = 150;
  this.ctx = ctx = this.$canvas[0].getContext('2d');
  this.rect = this.$canvas[0].getBoundingClientRect();
  this.squares = [];
  this.sqm = 50;
  
  this.tracker = 0;
  this.latestHover = {};
  
  this._events();
  this._prepare();
};

Canvas.prototype._events = function() {
  var self = this;
  
  this.$canvas.on('mousemove', function(e) {
    var posX = e.clientX - self.rect.left,
        posY = e.clientY - self.rect.top,
        newX = Math.floor(posX / self.sqm),
        newY = Math.floor(posY / self.sqm);
    
    if($.isEmptyObject(self.latestHover) || (self.latestHover.x !== newX || self.latestHover.y !== newY)) {
      self.latestHover.x = newX;
      self.latestHover.y = newY;
      
     self.squares.map(function(k, v) {
      let obj = self.squares[v];
      if(!obj.fixedBackground) obj.reverseBackgroundColor();
     });

      var square = self.findObject(newX, newY)[0];
      if(square) {
        square.setBackgroundColor('#ff0000');
        
        self.$currPos.html(newX +'x'+ newY);
        self._redraw();
      }
      
    }
  });
  
  this.$canvas.on('click', function() {
    if(self.tracker === 2) {
      return self._reset();
    }
  
    if(!($.isEmptyObject(self.latestHover))) {
      var x = self.latestHover.x,
          y = self.latestHover.y;
          
      var square = self.findObject(x, y)[0];
          square.setFixedBackground();
          
      self.$currClick.html(x +'x'+ y);
      self.setTracker();
    }
  });
  
};

Canvas.prototype._prepare = function() {
  for(var row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
    for(var col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
      this.squares.push(new Square(row, col, this.ctx, this.sqm));
    }
  }
};

Canvas.prototype._redraw = function() {
  var self = this;
  
  this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvasWidth, this.canvasHeight);

  this.squares.filter(function(k, v) {
    self.squares[v].draw();
  });
};

Canvas.prototype.setTracker = function() {
  this.tracker++;
  
  if(this.tracker === 2) this.$clickInfo.html('Click one more time to start over');
};

Canvas.prototype.findObject = function(x, y) {
  var self = this;
  
  return square = self.squares.filter(function(k, v) {
      var obj = self.squares[v];
      if(obj.posX === x && obj.posY === y) return obj;
    });
};

Canvas.prototype._reset = function() {
  var self = this;
  
  this.squares.map(function(k, v) {
    let obj = self.squares[v];
        obj.reverseBackgroundColor();
        obj.unsetFixedBackground();
  });
  
  this.$currClick.html('');
  this.$clickInfo.html('');
  this.tracker = 0;
  this._redraw();
};

var Square = function(x, y, ctx, sqm) {
  this.ctx = ctx;
  this.sqm = sqm;
  this.posX = x;
  this.posY = y;
  this.background = '#fff';
  this.strokeThickness = 1;
  this.fixedBackground = false;

  this.draw();
};

Square.prototype.setBackgroundColor = function(color) {
  return this.background = color;
};

Square.prototype.reverseBackgroundColor = function() {
  return this.background = '#fff';
};

Square.prototype.setFixedBackground = function() {
  return this.fixedBackground = true; 
};

Square.prototype.unsetFixedBackground = function() {
  return this.fixedBackground = false; 
};

Square.prototype.draw = function() {
  this.ctx.fillStyle = this.background;
  this.ctx.fillRect(this.posX * this.sqm, this.posY * this.sqm, this.sqm, this.sqm);
  this.ctx.strokeRect(this.posX * this.sqm, this.posY * this.sqm, this.sqm, this.sqm);
};

window.Canvas = new Canvas();
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas width="150" height="150"></canvas>
<div>
  Current position: <span id="currPos"></span> <br/>
  Last click: <span id="currClick"></span> <span id="clickInfo"></span>
</div>
```